# ConfigurationManager is not refreshing the AppSettings after a new execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

In my web application (c# + asp.net) I can use my new values on my config file (install.properties) when I try to get the values using "ConfigurationManager".

```
String pathJava = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePathJava"];
```

I have got this in my install.properties

```
<add key="FilePathJava" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"></add>
```

I rode that I can do this to refresh the values:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I also I did this:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration()
```

But the value does not change.

Also I tried to add a new key, but the ConfigurationManager returns me a null value.

Answer (score 1):

You have a potential problem...

If you change any value in the `Web.config`, while the site is running, it will reset the web site. Any modification whatsoever to this files causes an IIS reset to occur.

A solution to what you want, without resetting the web site is to move the application settings out of `Web.config` altogether:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings configSource="appSettings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

And now place your appSettings in the `appSettings.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="FilePathJava" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"/>
</appSettings>
```

Now, you can still use the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePathJava"]`, and your `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")` should work as well.

Comment: But I reseted IIS and re-run the web application with visual studio.

Comment: How about `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration/appSettings")` ?